# Why is my function not returning the expected result?

Tags: function, rust, return, return-value

My function is not returning the expected result. It's giving *0* instead of *2*, that is the result of *1 + 1*. Why is this happening and what could I do to fix it? Here is the code:

```
// Calculate the weight of a building

fn main() {
    let weight = sum(1, 1); //calling sum(1,1) and trying to bind its result to a variable
    println!("The result is {}.", weight); //printing "weight"
}

//function to perform "beams + columns" and use it in main()
fn sum(beams: u32, columns: u32) -> u32 {
    let beams: u32 = 0; 
    let columns: u32 = 0;

    beams + columns //Trying to return the result
}
```

Comment: You have two local variables declared: `let beams: u32 = 0;` and `let columns: u32 = 0;`, which you then add together. What do you expect 0 + 0 to be other than 0? The two local variables hide the ones you're getting as the parameters to the function. Delete those two local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created two variables that initalized to 0 in function sum, hence the result being 0.

You should delete these two variables in order to get the correct result.